# cloning/copying a dojo data store

Tags: dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojo

Hi can some one please tell me how to copy one data store to another in dojo. I tried it in following way but it doesn't work. Here I'm try to copy data from jsonStore to newGridStore.

```
jsonStore.fetch({query:{} , onComplete: onComplete});

var onComplete = function (items, request) {
    newGridStore = null;
    newGridStore =  new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data : {}
    });
    if (items && items.length > 0) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        var attributes = jsonStore.getAttributes(item);
        if (attributes && attributes.length > 0) {
            var j;
            for (j = 0; j < attributes.length; j++) {
                var newItem = {};
                var values = jsonStore.getValues(item, attributes[j]);
                if (values) {
                    if (values.length > 1) {
                    // Create a copy.
                    newItem[attributes[j]] = values.slice(0, values.length);
                    } else {
                        newItem[attributes[j]] = values[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        newGridStore.newItem(newItem);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you do it that way. Can you explain why you are trying to do this.

Comment: Becouse After updating the jsonStore with new values, I need to compare those with old values

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments asked above. You are trying to copy values to a new Store for the single reason to be able to detect which values have changes and then save them individually, without having to send the entire store.

This approach is totally wrong.

Dojo has `isDirty()` and offers you the ability to `revert()` a store back to it's original values. It knows which values have changed and you don't need to do this.

Take a look at the bog standard IFWS here: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore

Make sure you read everything from here: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore#id8

What you want to do is create your own `_saveCustom` method which you will override your store with, and then when you save, you will be able to see which values have changed.

**Click on the demo at the very bottom of the page. It shows you EXACTLY how do to it using _saveCustom**